# Using Highcharts with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack, highcharts

I seem to be unable to get WebPack to play nicely with Highcharts, I believe I have tried every variation of examples on the net but nothing seems to work, can someone help please?

If I check my `vendor.bundle.js` I have both `highcharts` and `highcharts-ng` contained within, but when my application (AngularJS) tries to load a chart I get the following error

```
Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined
    at initChart (VM6917221 highcharts-ng.js:334)
    at linkWithHighcharts (VM6917221 highcharts-ng.js:349)
```

If I try "Highcharts" or "window.Highcharts" at the command line it is not recognised.

If I goto my application entry point and add console.logs like so I see Highcharts being output to the console (and it happens before the error). So it seems something odd is happening

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
window["Highcharts"] = Highcharts;
(window as any).Highcharts = Highcharts;

console.log("1", Highcharts);
console.log("2", window["Highcharts"]);
console.log("3", (window as any).Highcharts);
import "highcharts-ng";
```

package.json

```
"@types/highcharts": "4.*",
"@types/highcharts-ng": "0.*",
"highcharts": "4.x",
"highcharts-ng": "0.x",
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this isnt working?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined` may also refer to an rendering error, I mean if the div that will contain the chart doesn't exist this error will occur too.

Comment: @Core972 Thanks, Im pretty sure this isnt the issue, as this worked perfectly before I moved to WebPack and the HTML / AngularJS code hasnt changed.  The actual line within highcharts-ng that has the error is ` chart = new Highcharts[chartType](mergedOptions, func);`

Comment: I’m not into this Highcharts or WbPack thing, but from what I see from your comment Chris, is that Highcharts seems to be an array of functions and its elements are indexed by chartType. Did you set chartType anywhere, cause I don’t see that in your example code.

Comment: @C.vanDorsten Thanks for replying, I have stepped through that function and everything is set but Highcharts is not available which I believe to be the root cause of the problem. If I cannot resolve this I will have to choose another charting provider

Comment: Maybe I’m stating the obvious, but you actually have the tag highchart in your webpage? Something like <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>. From what I read this is the placeholder for the chart.

Comment: Can you paste the complete and minimal files (package.json, js/html files, tsconfig?, webpack.config?) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Any solution to this yet @Chris?

Comment: @per_jansson I had to statically link to highcharts within my HTML. Its the only way I could get it to work